# How can I extract data from a CSV file into my RASA chatbot?

Tags: python, csv, rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core

I am developing a RASA chatbot, and I want to have a table (csv file) with fields like : book, year, points, author. How can I extract the data from that CSV file into my RASA chatbot? For example if I ask the chatbot:
In what year Percy Jackson and The Lightning Thief was published?
Answer: 2006 (answer provided from the CSV file)
or
Who's the author of the Intelligent Investor book?
Answer: Benjamin Graham (also from my CSV file)
or
How many points does that book have?
Answer: 100 points (from CSV)

How can I implement something like this ?
What would be the python code to make such a custom action?

Comment: did you try to use module `csv` or `pandas` to read `CSV`?

Comment: I am trying to read the csv using python and custom actions

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a custom action to do that. There's an example you might find helpful here: https://github.com/RasaHQ/financial-demo/blob/main/actions/profile_db.py that shows how to interact w. a database, but you can extend it to be any sort of data structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas to read the csv file.

Use the below code in the action.py file

```
from typing import Any, Text, Dict, List
from rasa_sdk import Action, Tracker
from rasa_sdk.executor import CollectingDispatcher
import csv
import pandas as pd

    class ActionReadCSV(Action):
        def name(self) -> Text:
            return "action_csv"
    
        def run(self, dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher,
                            tracker: Tracker,
                            domain: Dict[Text, Any]) -> List[Dict[Text, Any]]:
            df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/abc/filename.csv')
    
            for i, j in df.iterrows():
                dispatcher.utter_message(text=(str(j['ID']) + " " + str(j['Title'])))
            return []
```

Add the below in nlu.yml file:

```
- intent: csv
  examples: |
    - file
    - q_csv
    - TEST
    - test
    - Test
```

Use the below code in stories.yml:

```
- story: user query
  steps:
  - intent: greet
  - action: utter_greet
  - intent: csv
  - action: action_csv
  - intent: affirm
  - action: utter_happy
```

In your domain.yml, add a new section for custom actions like below:

```
actions:
  - action_csv
```

In rules.yml add the following:

```
- rule: Search the file when user gives input
  steps:
  - intent: csv
  - action: action_csv
```

Now save all the files & run your action server (`python -m rasa_sdk --actions actions`) and RASA server (`rasa run -m models --enable-api --cors "*" --debug`) in a separate terminal.